# Debugging SQL Server SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a complex query with many dozen joins and I get this message, am wondering how to debug (?) i.e. no column name or line number is quoted in the error message:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'X' to data type smallint.

I guess I just keep reducing the query until it works again and then add back bit by bit until error occurs again.

Comment: This is an issue with data. You're doing a CAST() or CONVERT() that tries to turn a VARCHAR value to a SMALLINT, and the value in the VARCHAR either isn't numeric or the resulting value after the conversion is too large to fit in a SMALLINT. Debugging means figuring out which columns are undergoing that conversion and then looking at the data to figure out what causes it. You can narrow it down by restricting the number of rows that are being processed into smaller sets until you find the area of the data where it's happening.

Comment: Thanks Ken ! Your answer is spot on .. ... I tried changing my CONVERT function calls to TRY_CONVERT and issue went away. I will do a data profile job (excel and formulas and macros) on the data table to determine where the data issue is !

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this can be easily debug as you found - using `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST`.

Something like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[DataSource]
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(SMALLINT, [MyTextColumn]) IS NULL;
```